Excel validation list filter out rows already used
I have a list of jobs/Projects in a table. There is an X in the first column if the job is completed.
On another tab I have a data validation list to select one of the job numbers (and information from that row)
Once a job is done (has an x) I no longer want it to show up in the list. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? (with no VB)
TAB 1




A
B
C
D
E





Hide
WO
name
type
description


1
X
123
Job1
fan
Fan  repair


2
X
124
Job2
Moto
Motor repair


3

125
Job3
Modem
Modem repair


4

126
Job4
Radar
Radar repair



TAB2



A
B
C
D
E




1
125 V
Job3
Modem
Modem repair


2
126 V
Job4
Radar
Radar repair


3
V






B1 Validation formulas
=TAB1!$B$1:$B$100
C2 Validation formula
=VLOOKUP(B1,TAB1!B:E,2,FALSE)
D2 Validation formula
=VLOOKUP(B1,TAB1!B:E,3,FALSE)
E2 Validation formula
=VLOOKUP(B1,TAB1!B:E,4,FALSE)
So when I select the WO number, the reset of the columns autofill. Pretty simple. I have hundreds of Items though and I don't want to sort through hundreds of numbers to get to the last wo on the list and was hoping I could hide all the x (closed or Hide) items and it only displayed those wo that were still open.
I hope this is makes it clear of what I'm trying to accomplish. This Hide column, at times I mark with a P for waiting parts, or W for waiting on customer and I can print reports for the specific status.

Please post your data as text, not image.

Also please show us exact how the data validation list on the other tab is setup

This question is similar to: Dynamic filtered named range in Excel?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Toto-I updated the question using text and the forums table. I hope that helps.  Cyber - I listed the validation formulas as you asked, Black cat-The true false doesn't work in this situation. Thank you for the link. I'm looking for an existing solution but if not a simple solution. Thanks everyone for your input.

For this, you need a helper column to apply the FILTER function. The data from this helper column will be used as the validation data range.
You can use an Excel table, but it is not necessary. If you use a table, the formula might be:
=FILTER(Table1[Job'#],Table1[Done]="")

And when defining a drop-down list, you can use a dynamic reference:
=Sheet2!$G$10#



Not sure if the 123 you show are validation list and if I put that =filter in the validation formula?

When I try to use filter I get a "function isn't valid" in office 2019

This solution requires excel 2021 or 365.
